# K8S baremetal nginx ingress controller not works

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I encountered a problem when integrating K8S nginx ingress. I installed the nginx ingress controller and established the testing ingress resources according to the instructions on the document, but I was not able to jump to the normal path. The test serive was normal and Accessible via cluster IP. Am I missing something?

> Install script

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml
```

> Bare-metal Using NodePort

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/service-nodeport.yaml
```

**Ingress controller is OK** 
[image]

> Testing ingress resource

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    app: my-nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: my-nginx
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: nginx1.beencoding.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx-1
          servicePort: 80
```

**We can see the test nginx pod raised and works fine, I can access the nginx index page by cluster IP**
[image]

**But I can't access nginx1.beencoding.com**
[image]

**Can't access via browser**
[image]

Comment: Can you try to curl your `ingress-nginx` service using the `NodePort` and provide your `nginx-1` service configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by setting `hostnetwork: true`

Answer (score 0):

It says **can't resolve**.

Either put the domain in `/etc/hosts/` file, or do the curl as follows:

`curl -H "Host: nginx1.beecoding.com" IP_ADDRESS`

Should work.

Comment: This domain name is available on the public network, it points to the public IP of my server。

Comment: Well, matter of fact, your curl can't resolve it. Can you curl google.com?